# Query postgresql database from cherryproxy

Tags: postgresql, flask

I have a `Postgresql` database and I'm using `Cherryproxy`. I would like to know if I can connect to the database from the proxy in order to do some queries and tweak the redirections according to the queries results.

Is it possible to do like in Flask applications:
`postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@server..` ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question, so what i did is the following:

`try:
          con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='' user='' host='' password=''")
     except:
          print ' can't connect to db '`